# Identifying multiple file types with bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, command-line

I'm pretty sure I've seen this done before but I can't remember the exact syntax.

Suppose you have a couple of files with different file extensions:

```
foo.txt
bar.rtf
index.html
```

and instead of doing something with all of them (`cat *`), you only want to run a command on 2 of the 3 file extensions.

Can't you do something like this?

`cat ${*.txt|*.rtf}`

I'm sure there's some `find` trickery to identify the files first and pipe them to a command, but I think bash supports what I'm talking about without having to do that.

Comment: Note - that's file extensions. You can also use the `file` command to get the actual type by inspection.

Comment: @Sobrique updated my question to be more correct.

Comment: You might also be thinking `find -exec` and `xargs` to run commands on a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax you want is `cat *.{txt,rft}`. A comma is used instead of a pipe.

```
$ echo foo > foo.txt
$ echo bar > bar.rft 
$ echo "bar txt" > bar.txt 
$ echo "test" > index.html
$ cat *.{txt,rft}
bar txt
foo
bar
$ ls *.{txt,rft}
bar.rft  bar.txt  foo.txt
```

But as [Anthony Geoghegan said in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33081851/identifying-multiple-file-types-with-bash/33082027#33082027) there's a simpler approach you can use.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, so thanks, although I may or may not use shell globbing. Thanks!

Comment: I've upvoted this as I didn't realise you could use Bash's curly braces expansion in conjunction with regular POSIX shell globbing.

Answer (score 2):

Shell globbing is much more basic than regular expressions. If you want to `cat` all the files which have a `.txt` or `.rtf` suffix, you'd simply use:

```
cat *.txt *.rtf
```

The glob patterns will be expanded to list all the filenames that match the pattern. In your case, the above command would call the `cat` command with `foo.txt` and `bar.rtf` as its arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way i use to do it using command substitution.
`cat $(find . -type f \( -name "*.txt" -o -name "*.rtf" \))`
But [Anthony Geoghegan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33081851/identifying-multiple-file-types-with-bash/33082027#33082027) is much simpler. I learned from it too.